# Vue scope fresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

I just use vue.js with jquery. My situation is, I tried to inject sidebar html code (with vue syntax inside) to main.html with jquery. However, after I injected sidebar.html to main.html, vue.js could not compile the vue's syntax of the injected one. So can anyone help me fix that problem?
Does vue has function like angular scope.apply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution to your problem is to mount your vue instance to the element after it has been injected by jquery. This is done by specifying it in the vue constructor with the [el](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#el) option. Or by using [$mount](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-mount)

It is hard to get jquery (the html parts of it) to run smootly with vue.js, I would suggest going vue all the way. One easy approach is to load all vue templates at once and then only change the data.

Comment: my problem is , I have to make many html pages with the same sidebar so I need to inject sidebar separately. Do you have another idea to do this?

Comment: Oh, thats something vue is really good at, no jquery needed. So if you just make a bundle out of your sidebar component and then include that bundle file into the html page.

<div id="mountId"></div>
<script src="sidebar.js"></script>

In order to make an js bundle, I would suggest trying out the [vue-cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli) and play around with the webpack-simple template.

Comment: Thank you. I will try it

Answer (score 0):

> Does vue has function like angular scope.apply?

As it says [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Async-Update-Queue), Vue performs DOM updates asynchronously. Whenever a data change is observed, it will open a queue and buffer all the data changes that happen in the same event loop. In the next event loop “tick”, Vue flushes the queue and performs the actual  work.

In order to wait until Vue.js has finished updating the DOM after a data change, you can use Vue.nextTick(callback) immediately after the data is changed. The callback will be called after the DOM has been updated, which is similar to AngularJS where you wrap the code in $apply() and starts a $digest cycle.

Code example:

**HTML**

```
<div id="example">{{ message }}</div>
```

**JS**

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    message: '123'
  }
})
vm.message = 'new message' // change data
vm.$el.textContent === 'new message' // false
Vue.nextTick(function () {
  vm.$el.textContent === 'new message' // true
})
```

Why your code did not work can be diagnosed after looking at the code only.

Comment: I injected my code with jquery and {{item.title}}{{item.detail}} could not be rendered.